# Multiplying a constant by a variable and a power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take $5\cdot (3x^2) = 15x^2$.

Why is the coefficient the only number to change?

Comment: 5 times 3 apples are 15 apples

Comment: why not equal 3x^10

Comment: $3(x^2)^5=3x^{10}$

Comment: @more-pepsi Do you know the rule for [exponenatiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)?

Comment: Please explain why you think that the result should be $3x^{10}$.

Comment: Let $y=x^2$. Then, $5\cdot (3y)$ should be less ambiguous.

Comment: Because with the distributive property the term is mapped onto coefficient, why is it not the case that its mapped onto the exponent.

Comment: The distributive property is for multiplication over addition, e.g., if the question were  $5\cdot(3+x^2)=5\cdot3+5\cdot x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the real numbers (i.e. $\mathbb{R}$) we have that the product $\cdot$ satisfies the **associative property**, that is
\begin{equation}
  \forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},\; (a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c) \tag{*}
\end{equation}
(Read "for all $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the real numbers, $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c)$").

I hope it's clear that, if $x$ is real, then $x\cdot x=x^2$ is real. So we can use (*) to conclude that
$$5\cdot(3\cdot x^2)=(5\cdot 3)\cdot x^2=15\cdot x^2.$$

In summary, the answer is due to $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ being a [*semigroup*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) (a fancy way of saying that the product is *associative* (*) on the real numbers). This concept is generalized on [abstract algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra).

Comment: What is the meaning of (*)

Comment: @more-pepsi It's the name a gave the statement "$\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},\; (a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c)$". Instead of writing it down again every time I want to state it, I name it $(*)$ and use that instead (for easy referencing).